# Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) on Debian

Tags: c, ssl, debian, libcurl

I wrote a program to test libcurl in C, here is the code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ret;
    static char buf[10000];
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.baidu.com");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, buf);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt");

            ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if (ret == CURLE_OK)
                    printf("OK\n");
            else {
                    size_t len = strlen(buf);
                    fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", ret);
                    if(len)
                            fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", buf,
                                    ((buf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
                    else
                            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(ret));
                    }
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

This code works fine with CentOS, but throw "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)" on debian, the CA file I specified is right and can be read, and when I run `curl -v https://www.baidu.com` in terminal, it shows

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

should I do some other steps when using Debian?